# Can I run 3 monitors simultaneously on an ASUS EAH5670 video card?

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Triple monitor setup is required. The PC only has space for 1 video card.

Can I attach 3 monitors to an ASUS EAH5670 video card?
The [specs](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/ati-radeon-hd-5670-overview/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-5670-overview.aspx#2) say that the card has three independent display controllers.

The card has got 3 outputs: 1 vga, 1 hdmi and 1 dvi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can attach three monitors.

Footnote 2 confirms this even more:

> ATI Eyefinity technology works with games that support non-standard aspect ratios which is required for panning **across three displays and to enable a third display** you require one panel with a DisplayPort connector.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using the ASUS EAH560 video card with the vga, hdmi and dvi outlet ports. I cannot get to 3 screen s running at the same time.
Regarding the Footnote 2 mentioned above:

> Footnote 2 confirms this even more:
>
> > ATI Eyefinity technology works with games that support non-standard aspect ratios which is >>required for panning across three displays and to enable a third display you require one >>panel with a DisplayPort connector.

I would like to point out that it REQUIRES a Display Port outlet, which is not present in either mine of your card. I have not tried the card with the Display Port, but do think I will do so soon.

Comment: For people who want to use 3 displays simultaneously: buy a HD5670. It is similar in setup.